# How do i call a method in Java from one class to another

Tags: java, methods, implementation

I have been asked to implement a method in a class called "CarHire" which already contains the following code

```
public static List<Customer> loadCustomers() {
    List<Customer> customers = null; 

    System.out.println("loadCustomers");
    return customers;
}
```

my other class TEXTCustomerDAO contains the method

```
public void loadCustomers(){
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("customers.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
```

how do i call the loadCustomer method in the CarHire Class?

i know its simple just hard to focus as uni is hellish at the moment so mild brain farts occur

Comment: `CarHire.loadCustomers()`, but it will return `null`.

Comment: The method in `CarHire` is static and thus can't be overridden. Sure you want it to be static? Note that there would be `super.loadCustomers()` to call the super class method in the subclass. Also note that you can't call a super class method on a subclass instance since that would break polymorphism (if you override a method you want it overridden and not let the caller decide whether to cirumvent that or not).

Comment: What class is abstract here?

Answer (score 0):

In Java functions are called `methods`.

1. Static methods can be called simply by `ClassName.methodName`
2. Non Static methods can be called when we have object of the
   class in which the method is present. Syntax : `new
   ClassName().methodName` If the constructor contains the parameters,
   pass the values for them.

> In CarHire.java you have a method which never initialize the local
>   variable `List<Customer> customers = null;` It is being printed and
>   also returned. This makes it useless and in turn makes the method useless. `customers` needs to be initialized and Customer object
>   references should be added in it.